# Unable to display a polygon using d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to append an svg using d3, as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.line {
  fill: yellow;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2.5px;
}

svg {
    border: 5px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}

</style>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", "M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z");

</script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't display anything. On the other hand, if replace the last three lines with the following, then I get a triangle.

```
<body>
<svg><path class="line" d="M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z"></path></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to figure out why this is. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess there's other errors, or perhaps your `script` isn't loading right, because it works fine in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2aK2S/

Try loading the `d3` in the `<head>`? (Which you don't seen to have on your page)

Comment: This seems more like a candidate for a comment, as it's saying there isn't enough information to answer, rather than an answer.

Comment: Fair enough, though this one and the answer below both pointed out the missing <head> tag which fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you @Rajkumar. I just tried different variations. The <head> tag appears dispensable but the <script> needs to be inside <body> in order to work. I always thought that <script> should appear before <body> but I must have been wrong. Once I put <script> inside <body>, the triangle loaded correctly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the <head> tag and not enclosing the <script> within the <body> tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>

    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .line {
      fill: yellow;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2.5px;
    }

    svg {
        border: 5px;
        height: 500px;
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 10px;
        min-width: 100px;
        min-height: 100px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script>
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", "M 100 100 L 300 100 L 200 300 z");

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```